# Bound for $e^{az-e^z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove $e^{az-e^z}$ is exponentially decreasing on the strip $\{x+iy:|y|<\pi/2\}$.

After some computation by definition, I got $|e^{az-e^z}|=e^{ax-e^x\cos y}$. But I got stuck here, since as $|y|$ goes to $\pi/2$, $\cos y$ would go to $0$. I can only show for each $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $C_\epsilon>0$ such that $e^{az-e^z}=e^{ax-e^x\cos y}\le e^{C_\epsilon e^x}$ as $x$ approaches to $\infty$ by bounding $|y|$ away from $\pi/2$. But I do not know how to prove $e^{az-e^z}$ is exponential decreasing as $|x|\to\infty$

Comment: What are the conditions on $a$?

Comment: @Gary $a>0$ sorry for that.

Comment: I am afraid that for $x>0$, you cannot have a uniform exponential decay.

Comment: @Gary Oh, yes I am finding exponential decay.

Comment: Exponential bound and exponential decrease are two different things. I think you are mixing up these two. Can you say what exactly you want to prove?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry for the confusion. Edited

Comment: the question is ambiguous; as @Gary notes, there is no uniform exponential decrease on the whole strip, but there is such pointwise/uniform on angles less than $\pi$ in the strip (which is how usually such bounds are required); so I would suggest to look at the context of the problem and clarify